# MySQL System Timezone using Abbreviation (AST) vs Olson Timezone (America/Curacao)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, timezone

I am working on a MySQL 5.7.41-44 instance running on a CentOS server.

The Linux timezone (per `timedatectl`) is `America/Curacao (AST, -0400)`.

The MySQL `@@system_time_zone` returns `AST` (and not `America/Curacao`).

The problem is that `AST` is not defined in the OS's zoneinfo files nor in MySQL's timezone tables, but 'America/Curacao` is.

Because MySQLs `@@system_time_zone` returns a timezone which isn't in the timezone tables, functions like `CONVERT_TZ([somedatetime], [fromTimeZone], @@system_time_zone)` do not work.

As far as I can tell, nothing timezone-related is being explicitly set in the MySQL config (and nothing specified in the startup command), so I am under the assumption that it is pulling `@@system_time_zone` from the OS.

Assuming that the host OS server's timezone can't be changed, how can I resolve this?

I guess either I need `AST` in the timezone tables in a best-practice way, OR, force mySQL to pick up the Olson timezone version (`America/Curacao` in this case), but I am unsure how to achieve that.

Comment: Have you tried `default-time-zone='America/Curacao'` in the [mysqld] section in my.cnf ?

Comment: Yes, that's the back-pocket solution I've had in mind, I am just trying to understand better how it all works when not explicitly set at the MySQL level.